# In Oracle DB: Is there a way to make LogMiner to escape some characters?

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to use 'LogMiner' in manner to synchronize DBs.

I've encountered a problem when a long clob containing the Single quote character (`'`) it won't escaped to the `''`, and I'm trying to find a way to tell the 'LogMiner' to escape it when it come from the table.

For example:
I have a table called TEXT_FILES with a name as `VARCHAR2` and file as `CLOB`, the `CLOB` is loaded from a text file. the file contains line like:

```
This won't work!!!
```

when it is a short file the LogMiner give me these commands:

```
insert into "TESTDB"."TEXT_FILES" ("NAME","FILE") values ('test1.txt',EMPTY_CLOB());
update "TESTDB"."TEXT_FILES" set "FILE"='This won''t work!!!' where "NAME"='test1.txt'
commit;
```

Note that the Single quote escaped and appear twice, this can run perfectly.

But when the file is long (i guess more then 1k bytes), and contains this line, the LogMiner generate a sort of procedure, like this:

```
insert into "TESTDB"."TEXT_FILES" ("NAME","FILE") values ('test2.txt',EMPTY_CLOB());
DECLARE
 loc_c CLOB;
 buf_c VARCHAR(6222)
...
BEGIN
 select "FILE" into loc_c from "TESTDB"."TEXT_FILES" where "NAME" = 'test2.txt' for update;
 buf_c := 'This won't work!!!This won't work!!! ........'; --(line continues) 
 dbms_lob.write(loc_c, 1024, 1, buf_c);
END;

 buf_c := '.... '; --file go on..
 dbms_lob.write(loc_c, 1024, 1025, buf_c);
END;

 buf_c := '.... '; --till end of file..
 dbms_lob.write(loc_c, 500, 2049, buf_c);
END;
```

(I don't know why it put an `END;` after each write, but this is a subject for another question...)

The point is that the single quote was not escaped automatically, and the script will fail to run.

I'm looking for a solution that should work for any file, (even file containing SQL queries, and even file containing the above procedure text, so I can't just look for a `buf_c :=` ) and it should work automatically.

So I wonder if anyone encounter this problem, and if anyone was able to solve it.

**EDIT:**

I'm using 'LogMiner' with these commands:
for each file from V$ARCHIVED_LOG with time newer then last sync: `DBMS_LOGMNR.ADD_LOGFILE` 
then I call to:

```
DBMS_LOGMNR.START_LOGMNR(OPTIONS=>DBMS_LOGMNR.DICT_FROM_ONLINE_CATALOG+DBMS_LOGMNR.NO_ROWID_IN_STMT);
```

Then: `Select SQL_REDO from v$logmnr_content` but it's a long script, that in the end, extract each change to a file, and files numbered chronologically.

Comment: What is the command you are using to generate the procedure?  Why are you using LogMiner directly for replication rather than using one of the replication technologies that leverages LogMiner (Streams, logical standby databases, etc.)?

Comment: It wasn't my decision to use LogMiner. Actually I will be glad to have a better way. but there is no direct connection between the two DBs, and I'm not a DBA so my knowledge is not so vast.